# Why doesn't gawk -d create awkvars.out in my current working directory?

Tags: awk

`gawk -d` does not [create `awkvars.out` in](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Options) my current working directory. Why?
Instead I get the following stdout:

```
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: gawk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:      GNU long options: (standard)
    -f progfile     --file=progfile
    -F fs           --field-separator=fs
    -v var=val      --assign=var=val
Short options:      GNU long options: (extensions)
    -b          --characters-as-bytes
    -c          --traditional
    -C          --copyright
    -d[file]        --dump-variables[=file]
    -D[file]        --debug[=file]
    -e 'program-text'   --source='program-text'
    -E file         --exec=file
    -g          --gen-pot
    -h          --help
    -i includefile      --include=includefile
    -l library      --load=library
    -L[fatal|invalid|no-ext]    --lint[=fatal|invalid|no-ext]
    -M          --bignum
    -N          --use-lc-numeric
    -n          --non-decimal-data
    -o[file]        --pretty-print[=file]
    -O          --optimize
    -p[file]        --profile[=file]
    -P          --posix
    -r          --re-interval
    -s          --no-optimize
    -S          --sandbox
    -t          --lint-old
    -V          --version

To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info'
which is section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the
printed version.  This same information may be found at
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bugs.html.
PLEASE do NOT try to report bugs by posting in comp.lang.awk,
or by using a web forum such as Stack Overflow.

gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

Examples:
    gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file
    gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

Comment: What command are you running?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual is admittedly misleading, or at least unclear. The issue is that you still need to give a program to gawk so it has something to run. At least in the case of `gawk`, you can pass it an empty string and that is enough:

```
$ gawk -d '' 
$ ls awkvars.out 
awkvars.out
```

And you can set a different file name with either:

```
gawk -dfoo.vars ''
```

or

```
gawk --dump-variables=foo1.vars ''
```

both of which will create `foo.vars`.

Comment: Strictly speaking, I wouldn't say it is unclear. Neither of the invocation forms allow omitting the program - one has it read from a file and the other has it specified in the command line, so in both cases a program has to be specified. Now in some options the program might be optional (I'd imagine so for the copyright and version ones), but the help text in the question doesn't imply the program is ever optional.

Comment: @muru When I read the manual, I also expected `gawk -d` to work. I had to go back up and check the description to see that a program is needed, but then, as you say, no program is needed for `-V` so why is one needed for `-d`. Anyway, I found it confusing, maybe others don't, but at least the OP and I did.